# Splitting variable content in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a variable in a stored procedure that contains a string of characters like

```
[Tag]MESSAGE[/Tag]
```

I need a way to get the `MESSAGE` part from within the tags.
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What is your database, `CHARINDEX` would work for SQL Server but not for all databases

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I have tested it on Oracle RDBMS

A more reliable approach is to use **REGEXP_REPLACE.**

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(value, pattern)
```

Example

```
SELECT  REGEXP_REPLACE(
        '<Tag>Message</Tag>',
         '\s*</?\w+((\s+\w+(\s*=\s*(".*?"|''.*?''|[^''">\s]+))?)+\s*|\s*)/?>\s*') FROM DUAL;
```

Just replace "<" with "[" if your tags are different

Comment: Says Regexp is no a built in function name for some reason

Comment: which RDMS are you using? is it MySQL ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(ColumnName,CHARINDEX('html_tag',ColumnName)+LEN('html_tag'),CHARINDEX('html_close_tag',ColumnName)-LEN('html_close_tag')) FROM TableName
```

You'll require to change the `html_tag` and `html_close_tag` with your own HTML tag that you want to get rid of.

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which dbms this is for.

Comment: It is for SQL server

Comment: It literally says it in the title

Answer (score 0):

If the column contains only single tag, simple call of `substring` function should be enough. Otherwise there will always be some point where regular expression does not suffice since you fall into [trap (see this legendary StackOverflow answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/653539).